# Write a dict on aws dynamodb as avS with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I would like to store a dictionary on dynamo DB so:

```
{"amount":"2.9","date":[]}
```

and I know how to do it with Haskell.

`formattedInfo = avS .~ info $ attributeValue` from `Network.AWS.DynamoDB`

but when I try it with python:

```
formatted_data = {'amount': str(data['amount']), 'date': data['date']}

if 'Item' in item_response:
    table.update_item(
        Key={
            's3ObjectKey': s3_key
        },
        UpdateExpression='SET kiData = :val1',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':val1': formatted_data
        }
    )
else:
    table.put_item(
        Item={
            's3ObjectKey': s3_key,
            'kiData': formatted_data
        }
    )
```

I get this `{ "amount" : { "S" : "2.9" }, "date" : { "L" : [ ] }}`

And it's not that bad, but it isn't as confortable as `{"amount":"2.9","data":[]}`

does anybody know, how I could do it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found the answer, I just need to store it as string:

```
formatted_data = {'amount': str(data['amount']), 'date': data['date']}

if 'Item' in item_response:
    table.update_item(
        Key={
            's3ObjectKey': s3_key
        },
        UpdateExpression='SET kiData = :val1',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':val1': str(formatted_data)
        }
    )
else:
    table.put_item(
        Item={
            's3ObjectKey': s3_key,
            'kiData': str(formatted_data)
        }
    )
```

or also this way, which for me fitted better:

```
formatted_data = {'amount': str(data['amount']), 'date': data['date']}

if 'Item' in item_response:
    table.update_item(
        Key={
            's3ObjectKey': s3_key
        },
        UpdateExpression='SET kiData = :val1',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':val1': json.dumps(formatted_data)
        }
    )
else:
    table.put_item(
        Item={
            's3ObjectKey': s3_key,
            'kiData': json.dumps(formatted_data)
        }
    )
```